# PlayN iOS Landscape mode

Tags: ios, landscape, playn

My game is designed for landscape only (screen resolution 1024*768 - iPad resolution).

My game scene is rendered correctly on every platform supported by PlayN (Android, html etc). The problem with iOS only.

I have prepared all the resources for iPad screen resolution, setup info.plist file, registered platform using `IOSPlatform.register(app, IOSPlatform.SupportedOrients.LANDSCAPES);`

When I run my application everything regarding device orientaton is correct, but game scene isn't fully rendered. It is rendered for the resolution 768*768 (Not all of the scene objects are visible - only objects that belong to 768*768 rect are visible) and the remaining screen space is black.

I've investigated the issue in the following way:

1. Applied scale transform to rootLayer (to make sure the entire scene is rendered). `PlayN.graphics().rootLayer().setScale(0.75f, 0.75f);`
   Result - game scene fits in 768*768 rect and I can see all game scene objects.
2. Applied translate transform to rootLayer (to make sure PlayN doesn't render scene outside of 768*768 rect).  `PlayN.graphics ().rootLayer().setTranslation(1024.0f - 768.0f, 0.0f);`
   Result - game scene is translated, but objects that are not belong to 768*768 screen rect are not visible.

My guess is that PlayN prepares its drawing context for the 768*1024 screen resolution (default iPad orientation resolution). When it renders the screen the objects located outside of 768*1024 rectangle are clipped (not rendered).

Any help or ideas what can cause such strange behavior would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following:

- iOS doesn't change main window frame and root view frame after device rotation (while Android does - I've checked).
- PlayN code expects that view size after rotation should be changed from 768*1024 (default orientation) to 1024*768.

Actual result: PlayN transforms game scene using transform matrix but doesn't change OpenGL framebuffer size (framebuffer size is still 768*1024)

I've fixed this issue by adding the next piece of code to `IOSGLContext`:

```
@Override
public void setSize (int width, int height)
{
    if (UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft == orient || UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight == orient)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Swap IOSGLContext width and height for " + UIDeviceOrientation.wrap(orient));
        viewWidth = height;
        viewHeight = width;
    }
    else
    {
        viewWidth = width;
        viewHeight = height;
    }
    super.setSize(viewWidth, viewHeight);
}
```

Now everything work as expected!

If you have any other ideas how to fix this issue I will be glad to discuss them)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

download the latest PlayN-1.5 snapshot (from -> https://github.com/threerings/playn not from google code). This issue is fixed in that version